# how to parse a search query string like SO

Tags: c#, sql, regex, entity-framework, parsing

I want to build a searching function with keywords format on Entity Framework.

```
void funcSearch(string keywork)
        {
            if (keywork == "[tag]")
            {
                //regex for is tag
                //do search tag
            }
            if (keywork == "user:1234")
            {
                //regex for userid is 1234
                //do search user with 1234
            }
            ...
        }
```

Can i use regex to parse a query string format like SO, or any method? a function to to be able to analyze all of the cases with corresponding keyword?

```
tags    [tag]
exact   "words here"
author  user:1234
user:me (yours)
score   score:3 (3+)
score:0 (none)
answers answers:3 (3+)
answers:0 (none)
isaccepted:yes
hasaccepted:no
inquestion:1234
views   views:250
sections    title:apples
body:"apples oranges"
url url:"*.example.com"
favorites   infavorites:mine
infavorites:1234
status  closed:yes
duplicate:no
migrated:no
wiki:no
types   is:question
is:answer
```

thank you for advice.

Comment: You could.  Or, you could just use `String.Split()`

Comment: I don't understand what your raw search data is going to look like. Literally a query string as in `?something=value&anotherThing=another Value`?

Comment: why parse the querystring if you can just iterate over it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. You'd have to create a list of regular expressions to check and loop through them until you find a match. (Make sure to prioritize them correctly.)

For example, to find out if a search query is querying tags, you can use the following regex:

```
string query = "[tag]";
bool isTag = Regex.IsMatch(query, @"^\[.+?\]$");
```

Here's another regex matching a user ID:

```
string query = "user:1234";
var match = Regex.Match(query, @"^user:(\d+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Note that you should trim your `query` first.

Comment: Maybe I should learn more about regex, to be able to analyze all of the cases. thank for advice